# forEach array function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a method code like below.

```
static transformModel(control: AbstractControl,companyId:number):aDTO[]
{
    let finalRequestObj: aDTO[] = new Array();
    let request: aDTO;
    let counter: number = 0;
    let questionArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

    questionArray.forEach( num =>{
            counter= counter+1;
            request={
                userSeqId:0,//should be updated on server side
                companyId: companyId,
                questionId : counter,
                versionNumber : eueVersion,
                answer  :  findAnswer(counter,control),
                confirmTimeStr : "",
                screen : SCREEN
            };
            if(request.answer) {
                finalRequestObj.push(request);
            }
        }
    )

    return finalRequestObj;
}
```

In above method how can I not use `counter` variable and use the `questionArray` values to assign to `questionId` inside request object?

Comment: This smells like Typescript, not Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The forEach array method has a second parameter that gets passed to it that represents the index of each element:

```
questionArray.forEach( (num, counter) =>{
            request={
                userSeqId:0,//should be updated on server side
                companyId: companyId,
                questionId : counter,
                versionNumber : eueVersion,
                answer  :  findAnswer(counter,control),
                confirmTimeStr : "",
                screen : SCREEN
            };
            if(request.answer) {
                finalRequestObj.push(request);
            }
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **the values** inside the array, just use the value `num` provided by [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), like this:

```
questionArray.forEach( num =>{
        request={
            // ...
            questionId : num,
            // ...
        };
       //...
    }
)
```

---

On the other hand if you want to use something like an **auto-incremental** value taking the array as reference, use the value [`index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Syntax) provided by `forEach` as second argument, like this:

```
questionArray.forEach( (num, index) =>{
        request={
            // ...
            questionId : index,
            // ...
        };
       //...
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is index ([foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)), then so :

```
questionArray.forEach( (num, index) =>{
   // use index variable
}
```